# how to remover [,] brackets while inserting into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello sir i am send the array list android to php through url it is also inserting succesfully but start[ and end ] this brakets also inserted i want remove it

i try the following code ..

```
<?php
    $arr=explode(',',preg_replace('/^\[(.*)\]$/','$1',$_POST['menuname']));
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    mysql_select_db("test");
    foreach($arr as $value){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES ('" . 
        mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "')")or
        die('unable'.mysql_error());
        echo "inserted";
    }
?>
```

please how to remove the bracket start and end please tell me

Comment: There is no need to say hell hi here just post your question directly

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about PHP but in Mysql it's like that

```
INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES (replace(replace(value, '[', ''), ']', ''))
```

Comment: PHP is pretty much the same, all you will have to add is the syntax to add to the database `mysql_query` ... So it will be `mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES (replace(replace(value, '[', ''), ']', ''))";` 
You can also use the replace function in the PHP before sending the data to the MySQL `str_replace()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: i can add mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES (replace(replace(value, '[', ''), ']', ''))"; this line means the array list cannot insert to the database please  tell me how

Comment: please replay for my question

Comment: @prakash: Did you try `mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES (replace(replace(" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . " , '[', ''), ']', ''))"` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like this:
[menu1,menu2,menu3]
then you could use substr to dump the brackets and then explode to break it up, like so:

```
$arr=explode(',',substr($_POST['menuname'],1,-1))

...

foreach($arr as $value){
$val=mysql_real_escape_string($value);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES ('" . $val . "')")or
        die('unable'.mysql_error());

...
```

BTW. You can insert multiple rows in one go in mysql by creating one longer query:

```
INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES (value1), VALUES(value2) ....
```

Comment: no my out put like theis[menu1,menu2,menu3]..now i want remove first braket and last braket

Comment: I have changed my answer above to match, substr takes two numerical parameters (second and third parameter), second one tells index of first character (they start at 0) and the third one if negative how many characters to skip at the end.